# Что нужно для модального окна?

Tags: html, ajax

Имеется некая форма для ввода данных и кнопка для отправки этих данных. Если я хочу сделать вывод отправленных данных не на новой странице, а на этой же в модальном окне, значит ли это, что стоит использовать ajax, а не "form", или отображение успешности операции можно сделать не затронув "form".

Comment: Вы пишите про "новую страницу", хотя решить вы для себя должны другое - вывод результата без перезагрузки страницы или таковая допускается. Ведь во втором случае, вам не обязательно выводить результат на новой; в конце концов, после обработки запроса, можно сделать редирект на ту же страницу с тем или иным сообщением о завершении операции.

Comment: @Deonis мне просто хочется понять нужно ли переделывать все под ajax, или возможно вывести модальное окно с полученными в форме значениями на той же самой странице.( В принципе новая страница допускается) И какой форма по вашему мнению был бы более удобен для пользователя: модальное всплывающее окно на той же странице или же "новая" станица(неважно будь то с перезагрузкой или без, пользователь вряд ли заметит)?

Comment: Я уже написал, что можно обойтись и без Ajax, хотя каких-то особых причин его не использовать, я тоже не вижу. Не хотите заморачиваться? Значит просто делайте редирект на ту же страницу, но с каким-то GET-параметром, указывающим на статус выполненной операции. На странице у вас уже могут быть заготовлены несколько вариантов вывода, в зависимости от значения этого параметра. Проверяете - если есть такой параметр, то открываем модальное окно с тем или иным сообщением. Для редиректа, если на сервере у вас PHP, используем функцию [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать [iframe](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe) внутри модального окна и не использовать ajax, а отправлять форму стандартным способом. Для этого надо будет сделать отдельную страницу с формой, которую вы загрузите в iframe, и страницу с результатами отправки.